# How to throw error when we accidently import cyclic?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to separate javascript files into chunks.

My expected result: This should not work and throw an error of cyclic import.

My actual result: The `index.html` can import `app.js` without problem.

This is a part of WebRTC example that I am going to separate into chunks.

app.js

```
// localVideo

const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');

localVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  console.log(`Local video videoWidth: ${this.videoWidth}px, videoHeight: ${this.videoHeight}px`);
});

// startButton

const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

startButton.addEventListener('click', start);

let localStream;

async function start() {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;
    startButton.disabled = true;
    callButton.disabled = false;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(`start() error: ${e}`);
  }
}

// remoteVideo, callButton, hangupButton (skipped for brevity)
```

After writing everything in one file. I decided to make the file into chunks. This is the cyclic import. First, `app.js import from startButton.js`. However, `startButton.js import from app.js to get localStream.`

app.js

```
import * as startButton from "./startButton.js"

export let localStream;
```

startButton.js

```
import { localStream } from "./app.js";
// startButton

const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

startButton.addEventListener('click', start);

// let localStream; // moved to ./app.js because I am going to use it in callButton.js as well.

async function start() {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;
    startButton.disabled = true;
    callButton.disabled = false;
  } catch (e) {
    alert(`start() error: ${e}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: @A_A i wish to throw `cylic import` error if the compiler detect `cyclic import`.

Comment: What compiler? You didn't mention any in the question. Webpack, ...?